# Passing multiple arguments into map() with prop.test() with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

could anybody help my to change the `rowwise()` + `prop.test()` to `map2`?
The issue is, that `map2` takes .x and .y arguments, but I need to pass 4 columns: 2xsucces and 2xtries into the `prop.test()` function. I want to extract the p-value into new column `p`.

This code runs OK'isch:

```r
library(tidyverse)

cc <- tribble(
    ~n1, ~x1, ~n2, ~x2,
    1000,100,900,85,
    1000,100,100,10,
    1000,100,10,10
)

cc %>%
    rowwise()%>%
    mutate(p = prop.test(x=c(x1, x2), 
                         n=c(n1, n2), 
                         conf.level=0.95)$p.value)%>%
    mutate(p=round(p,5))
#> Warning in prop.test(x = c(x1, x2), n = c(n1, n2), conf.level = 0.95): Chi-
#> squared approximation may be incorrect
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#> # Rowwise: 
#>      n1    x1    n2    x2     p
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  1000   100   900    85 0.741
#> 2  1000   100   100    10 1    
#> 3  1000   100    10    10 0
```

But I noticed that I can gain speed with a for loop:

```r
cc <- tribble(
    ~n1, ~x1, ~n2, ~x2,
    1000,100,900,85,
    1000,100,100,10,
    1000,100,10,10
)

cc %>%
    rowwise()%>%
    mutate(p = prop.test(x=c(x1, x2), 
                         n=c(n1, n2), 
                         conf.level=0.95)$p.value)%>%
    mutate(p=round(p,5))


cc$p <-999

for (i in 1:nrow(cc)){
    result <-  prop.test(x=c(cc$x1[[i]], cc$x2[[i]]),
                         n = c(cc$n1[[i]], cc$n2[[i]]), 
                         conf.level=0.95)
    cc$p[[i]] <- result$p.value
}

cc %>%
    mutate(p=round(p,5)) 
}
```

But I ask myself it there is more elegant way to use `map` function from `dplyr` in order to write less code and achieve the same results?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `pmap`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

cc <- tribble(
  ~n1, ~x1, ~n2, ~x2,
  1000, 100, 900, 85,
  1000, 100, 100, 10,
  1000, 100, 10, 10
)

cc %>%
  mutate(
    signif = list(x1, x2, n1, n2) %>% pmap_dbl(~ {
      prop.test(
        x = c(..1, ..2),
        n = c(..3, ..4),
        conf.level = 0.95
      )$p.value
    })
  )
#> Warning in prop.test(x = c(..1, ..2), n = c(..3, ..4), conf.level = 0.95): Chi-
#> squared approximation may be incorrect
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>      n1    x1    n2    x2   signif
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1  1000   100   900    85 7.41e- 1
#> 2  1000   100   100    10 1   e+ 0
#> 3  1000   100    10    10 9.46e-18
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

For loops are usually very slow, and the code is hard to read and often unnecessary when it comes to the scenario of just apply a function for each element.
The thing which slows down your `dplyr` code is rowwise, which is not needed anymore using the `map` function.